# Yii 1.1 CLinkPager generated uncomplete url

Tags: php, yii

I'm new in Yii 1.1. and i have a problem in generating url using CLinkPager. 
The right url is http://example.com/read/group/car?page=2 [baseurl/controller/action/id?page_number] but yii 1.1 CLinkPager generated wrong url (http://example.com/read/group?page=2) and missed */car.

my config/main.php is like

```
... 
'urlManager'=>array(
'urlFormat'=>'path',
'showScriptName'=>false,
'rules'=>array(
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/*<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
),
),
...
```

How configure yii to get the right url? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: so `car` is the id? This willnot work, because your rules say, that the `id` is a digit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having a problem with your rules, replace them with:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```

You tried to use `<id:\d+>` but `\d` stands for digit. so you need to replace it with `\w` (word character)

Comment: Be careful, because `\w` matches only word characters. In this case `car` will match your rule, but `old-car` – don't. You can use `[^\/]+` instead of `\w+`